# Get request address of XMLRpcRequest

Tags: java, p2p

I have the following code

```
public Object execute(XmlRpcRequest xmlRpcRequest) throws XmlRpcException {
```

I want to get the ip address of the request, but this class doesn't offer this. It doesn't have a methode named getHostAddress() or something like that. Is there a way to archieve this?

Comment: Which XmlRpcRequest are we talking about here? i.e. What package does it come from?

Comment: Sorry. It comes from org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcRequest

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at the type returned by the getConfig method. This says it returns an interface of type XmlRequestConfig but the actual type returned will depend on the underlying transport used. If you are using the correct transport then the underlying config class should have a method to get the host name or server url.